# Hiding elements in a Kendo Utility Window based on the button clicked

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

OK relatively new to all this:  I have a Kendo Grid where the customer Id is auto-generated based on the customer, year, and how many times the customer has been helped.  To make a new copy with a different address or service it opens a utility window, you choose the company, it makes the Id and you fill in the fields.  I would also like to use this to update customer records with an edit button opening the same utility window but hiding the Pick company drop down as the Id is already created.

This is on the main page:

```
<script>
function closeWindow(e) {
    $(this.element).empty();
}

function editJobs(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

    var win = $("#utilityWindow").data("kendoWindow");
    win.refresh({ url: "/BackendSchedule/_Jobs?jobId=" + dataItem.Id});
    win.setOptions({
        title: "Edit Jobs",
        width: 1000,
        height: 600,
    });
    win.center().open();

}

function newJobs() {
    var win = $("#utilityWindow").data("kendoWindow");
    win.refresh({ url: "/BackendSchedule/_Jobs?jobId="});
    win.setOptions ({
        title: "Add New Jobs",
        width: 1000,
        height: 600,
    });
    win.center().open();
}
```

Here is the Window

```
<form id="JobForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset class="input">
        <p class="info">

        </p>
        <p id="buildJobId" class="hidden">
            <label for="storeType">Store Type</label>
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                .Name("storeType")
                .OptionLabel("please select")
                .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData["jobtypes"])
                .Events(e => e.Change("storeTypeChange"))
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:275px;" })
            )
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Id">Id</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id, new { @class = "k-textbox", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </p>
        <p>
             <label for="Company">Company Name</label>
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                .Name("Company")
                .OptionLabel("Please Select")
                .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData["company"])
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:275px;" })
                )
        </p >
        <p>

            <label for="Address1">Address</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address1, new { @class = "k-textbox" })<br/> 
            <p> 
                <label for="Address2"></label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address2, new { @class = "k-textbox" })
            </p>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="City">City</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City, new { @class = "k-textbox" })
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="State">State</label>
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                .Name("State")
                .OptionLabel("Please Select")
                .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData["states"])
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px;" })
            )
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="ZipCode">Zip Code</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ZipCode, new { @class = "k-textbox" })
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="ContactName">Contact Name</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactName, new { @class = "k-textbox"})
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Phone">Phone</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone, new { @class = "k-textbox", type = "tel" })
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Email">Email</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "k-textbox", required = "required" })
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="TimeAllowed">Time Allowed</label>
            @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="PlanStartDate">Plan Start Date</label>
            @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.PlanStartDate))
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="PlanEndDate">Plan End Date</label>
            @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.PlanEndDate))
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="ReponsibleParty">Responsible Party</label>
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                .Name("Contact")
                .OptionLabel("Please Select")
                .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData["responsibleParty"])
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px;" })
            )
        </p>

        <p>
            <button class="k-button" id="submitForm" name="submitForm" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <button class="k-button right" id="cancelButton" type="button">Cancel</button>
        </p>
        <div id="message" class="text-danger"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The Id=buildJobId that is hidden right now will need to be displayed on the create new button.

Here is the code I thought would work:

```
        if ($("#Id").data("TextBoxFor").dataSource.data(null)){
            $("#buildJobId").show();
        } else {
            $("#buildJobId").hide();
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added a little more code but got it to work on the last part I have connected it to the function that will be called:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $("#JobForm").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
    var postUrl = "/BackendSchedule/Jobs_Update";

    if ("@ViewBag.Id".length == 0) {
        postUrl = "/BackendSchedule/Jobs_Create";
        $("#buildJobId").show();
    } else {
        $("#buildJobId").hide();
    }
```